# Where is the source that Tzaddikim will be ressurected before others?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, resurrection-of-the-dead

I remember reading that Tzaddikim will get up by Techiat Hameitim right when Moshiach comes and everyone else 40 years later. What is the source for this?

Comment: This is going to drive me nuts. I’ve heard of this before as well, but I can’t seem to find it.

Comment: It's mentioned without a source here: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D#cite_ref-2

Comment: As well as here with a source that doesn't actually seem to say as much. (Notably, they also quote the Lubavitcher Rebbe, z"l, who interpreted that all Yisrael are revived at the first stage of techitat hameitim.) http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D#cite_ref-27

Comment: Not surprised if it’s (mistakenly) based on a Zohar in Toldot.

Comment: In addition to the secondary sources I link to in my answer, I believe the Artscroll Schottenstein Talmud volume on Sanhedrin perek chelek has a nice introductory summary of the different views on Techiyat Hameitim.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Rav Uriel Eitam](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/ktav_et/maamarim/etam14617.pdf) (footnote 5), Rav Saadia Gaon in his [Emunoth V'Deoth, treatise 7](https://www.sefaria.org/HaEmunot_veHaDeot%2C_%5BTreatise_VII%5D_The_Resurrection_of_the_Dead.1?lang=bi), seems to interpret that there will be two separate revivals of the dead, a first one to reward Israel, and a second one to punish the wicked.

According to [an article on the topic in Chabadpedia](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D#cite_ref-23), the [Zohar](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar?lang=bi) (1:139:1), says that the ingathering of the exiles will precede the revival of the dead by 40 years.  The Chabadpedia article likewise claims that a revival of the righteous at the beginning of the messianic era is derivable from [Yoma 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.5b.7?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).

Comment: Do you have a link to the exact place in the Zohar?

Comment: @ezra Honestly, at least with what little time I have now, I was having trouble finding *any* of the primary references.  Also, as I noted in my comment on the question, I don't see how the author of the Chabadpedia article makes his deduction from the passage in Yoma either.

Comment: @Loewian In particular, if you are bringing a source from Chabad, you need to clarify precisely what is meant by "the ingathering of the exiles". It is not understood according to the teachings of Chabad like most people understand it.

Comment: Also, regarding the statement from Saadia Gaon, he is not limiting the resurrection to 2 periods. There are many more than that. The secondary period that he mentions in regard to "the wicked" is referring to the the Day of Judgement for the non-Jewish nations, who will also experience resurrection.

Comment: see what we learn from Yoma 5b here, and some sources of some of the commentaries who discuss it: https://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/2312389/jewish/Chapter-6-When-Will-the-Resurrection-Take-Place.htm#footnote13a2312389   _See Aruch LaNer on Niddah 61b; Tosafos on Pesachim 114b; Yoma 5b; Ikkarim 4:35. Midrash Rabbah, at the end of Parshas Eikev, states that Moshe Rabbeinu will come together with Eliyahu HaNavi (the Prophet Elijah)..._